# Нужен ли ReactJs для верстальщика?

Tags: javascript, frontend

Для чего в основном нужен React? И нужно ли его изучать для вёрстки сайтов?

Comment: Конкретно для вёрстки он не нужен. Фреймворки по типу React, Angular и Vue используются для создания полноценных фронтенд приложений

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если хочешь заниматься конкретно версткой, то нет, но если хочешь дальше развиваться в frontend, то будет большим плюсом